# how to split after delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble of finding a way to get the substring from a hostname.
The hostname is of the format `oraclehost.server.region.net`,which is the full server name(FQDN).

From this I want to retrieve the short hostname which is `oraclehost`
Can you please suggest?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: For Postgres: `split_part(the_column, '.', 1)`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: See [REGEXP_SUBSTR extract everything before specific character](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2018/07/20/regexp_substr-extract-everything-before-specific-character/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the code mentions Oracle, I will suggest an Oracle solution:

```
select regexp_substr(hostname, '^[^.]+')
```

Comment: is there a way to add a '%' at the end of the extracted string

Comment: @vivek Just append like this `regexp_substr(hostname, '[^.]+') || '%'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff You don't need the `^` outside the `[`

Comment: @LalitKumarB . . . It would be necessary if the string started with a `.` -- which probably isn't possible.  More importantly, it makes the pattern clearer to me:  "get the initial characters before the first period".

Comment: how can i get the other part of the string like ".server.region.net"

Comment: You would use `regexp_replace(hostname, '^[^.]+', '')`.